# How to lag and get first value base on condition on bigquery sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a table and want to return the session_id where rn=1 for each customer, rn is not always the same.
rn here is row_number over (partition by customer_id, order_id by date_key) rn

| customer_id | session_id | order_id | date_key | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2342 | A123 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2343 | A125 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2344 | A126 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 2 | 2345 | A127 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2346 | A128 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2346 | A129 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 2 | 2346 | A130 | 2022-01-01 | 4 |

| customer_id | session_id | order_id | date_key | rn | firstSession |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2342 | A123 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2342 |
| 1 | 2343 | A125 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 2342 |
| 1 | 2344 | A126 | 2022-01-01 | 3 | 2342 |
| 2 | 2345 | A127 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2345 |
| 2 | 2346 | A128 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 2345 |
| 2 | 2346 | A129 | 2022-01-01 | 3 | 2345 |
| 2 | 2346 | A130 | 2022-01-01 | 4 | 2345 |

I could basically do a

```
with firstsession as
(select * from table1 where rn=1)

select 
 t1.* 
 ,fs.session_id firstSession
from table1 t1
left join 
   firstsession fs 
   on t1.customer_id=fs.customer_id and t1.date_key=fs.date_key
```

How do I do a lag function to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  first_value(session_id) over session as firstSession
from your_table
window session as (partition by customer_id order by date_key)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]